# eclipse.jdt.ls reports compile error(package not exist). but code completion works

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to use `coc-java` for java development. Everything seems to be fine before I import JAR file.I wrote `build.gradle` like this:

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'eclipse'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
  testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}
```

Code conpletion works fine. `gradle test` runs well. But coc-java shows compile error like this:

```
src/test/java/sample/gradle/HelloWorldTest2.java|3 error| package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
```

[Code completion works fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHNVe.png)

[False compile error is reported like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTxv.png)

I'm confusing... Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem.

The error message was printed by `syntastic`.
I was solved by adding `let g:syntastic_java_checkers = []` to `.vimrc` (or ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.